# Issue with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

I understand that ASIHTTPRequest project is abandoned by Ben, but anyway its too late now for me to switch to something else so I decided to try to deal with the issue I have.

I'm POSTing and a request with https protocole. 
I've disabled persistence connection on request.

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    [request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];

    // Set the request timeout 
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:REQUEST_TIME_OUT];


    // Upload an image
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageContainer.mImage);
    [request setPostBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:imageData]];;

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

And all what I'm getting `A connection failure occurred` with the `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005`.

I've enabled all DEBUG info in configs of the `ASIHTTPRequest` project and have got following log

```
[STATUS] Starting asynchronous request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x1029e000>
[CONNECTION] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x1029e000> will not use a persistent connection
[THROTTLING] ===Used: 0 bytes of bandwidth in last measurement period===
[THROTTLING] ===Used: 327680 bytes of bandwidth in last measurement period===
[CONNECTION] Request attempted to use connection #(null), but it has been closed - will retry with a new connection
[CONNECTION] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x1029e000> will not use a persistent connection
[THROTTLING] ===Used: 229376 bytes of bandwidth in last measurement period===
[THROTTLING] ===Used: 360448 bytes of bandwidth in last measurement period===
[CONNECTION] Request attempted to use connection #(null), but it has been closed - we have already retried with a new connection, so we must give up[STATUS] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x1029e000>: Failed
[CONNECTION] Request #(null) failed and will invalidate connection #(null)ata upload failed "Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0xf624750 {NSUnderlyingError=0xf6246f0 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"
```

Any ideas why the crash happens ? and how to fix this ?

Comment: Please.. add the code that is invoking this error. From the error alone its hard to find the problem.

Comment: Update the post with the code, but its really very standard call I guess.

Comment: The [1005 error](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost) could mean that the host you are connecting with has closed the connection or you connect is really bad. Does the host have an self singed certificate?

Comment: can you post the url that you use for the request? is the url valid?

Comment: no I can't post it. The URL is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for trying to help.

I just figured it out the problem was caused by server side. Which refused to accept data larger let say 800K.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue several months ago. Internet connections are not guaranteed and you will find this error is more common on a 3G connection. My solution was to raise the retry count. Inside of `ASIHTTPRequest.m` modify the retry count to at least 5 and see if that helps.

```
- (BOOL)retryUsingNewConnection
{
    if ([self retryCount] < 5) {
```

The reason why this works is because error `-1005` is caught in `-handleStreamError` then the connection is retried as many times as allowed in the above code.